# netsh set multiple hostednetwork

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, netsh

I am trying to use two WIFI adapters to form a WLAN network. I know the following command can setup a hostednetwork and I have already done it.

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork [[mode={allow|disallow}] [[ssid=]WirelessNetworkName] [[key=]passphrase] [[keyUsage=]{persistent|temporary}]
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

However, the hostednetwork that I had setup is automatically mirror to the first adapter. How I can setup another hostednetwork that mirror to the second adapter? I have searched in the internet for long time but still cannot get a solution. Thandks.

Comment: same here. Seems that the `wlan set hostednetwork` command needs an `interface` argument to be added.

Answer (score 1):

According to my previous search, it's up to the windows to automatically chose which adapter is suitable, and you can't change that.
A work around might work, try it then report back to me the results:

1. Delete already setup-ed hostednetwork
2. Disable all the wireless adapters except the one you want to setup the hostednetwork on it
3. Setup hostednetwork
   And no, you can't setup 2 hostednetworks.

Comment: That could be a solution except if you want your hosted network to bridge from another interface. Example: Interface A is how you get internet, interface B is the one you want be the host for the network.

Comment: You can re-enable disabled adapter(s) after hosted network setup https://superuser.com/a/1223572/523095